# TweenLite rejects to animate object

Tags: animation, gsap

I got a div with the id "start". When I click on it I want to let it move. I added an onclick event on to the function "Move();"

For some reason TweenLite rejects to animate the object.

```
 function Move() {
    console.log("test");
    var startCircle = document.getElementById("start");
    TweenLite.to(startCircle, 1, {x:1});
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what may cause this?

Update:

I get no errors in the console, neither any warnings. The log shows up in the console though so I know that the function is executed.

TweenLite is loaded in the head tags using the following line

```
<script src="bower_components/greensock/src/minified/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
```

And it's for the following div:

```
<div onclick="Move();" class="eclipse white center" id="start"></div>
```

Comment: Could you provide additional information, like any errors you might be getting, any information send to console etc, what have you tried to resolve the issue, post more of your code if you think it will help. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good reference on asking good questions that will get you the best response.

Comment: Are you loading the GSAP CSSPlugin? .. It is required when you want to animate CSS properties such as **x** (translateX). TweenLite does not include the CSSPlugin in TweenLite. But **TweenMax** does include the CSSPlugin for convenience. Visit the CSSPlugin Docs for more info: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/Plugins/CSSPlugin/ .. Also see the TweenMax Docs: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/Animation/TweenMax/

Comment: I noticed you're only animating literally 1 pixel to the right (x:1), so perhaps it's animating fine but you just don't really see it because it's animating 1 pixel over the course of 1 full second. Remember, x:1 is like transform:translateX(1px) which is like an offset from the element's "normal" position in the document flow. It's not an absolute pixel coordinate on the stage/page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if GSAP libraries (CSS plugin included) are loaded. Be sure your Move() function is declared AFTER your div button has been loaded.